# Change tab from code using ubuntu SDK

Tags: qt, qml, sdk

How to change tab using code in QML in Ubuntu SDK?

The answer is:

If tabs are defined as follows:

```
Tabs {
        id: tabs
        .....
}
```

then using this:

```
tabs.selectedTabIndex = 0
```

will get you the first tab, 1 for second and so on. Unfortunately, `selectedTabIndex` is the only non-read-only attribute so there isn't something similar to push method in pageStack.

Comment: Remember we are a Q&A site - so come back tomorrow and post your answer as an answer.  You will then be able to accept your answer to close the thread.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [current Documentation on **Tabs**](http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/apps/qml/current/Ubuntu.Components.Tabs/#selectedTabIndex-prop), the currently selected tab is now writable and can be used to change the active tab.